# batch - values from different lines into a new one

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a small problem that I would like to try to solve with a batch.

My input file (.txt) has the following structure:

```
Name1;Name2;Street;;;;;;;;;;3;123;
Name1;Name2;Street;;;;;;;;;;3;12345;
Name1;Name2;Street;;;;;;;;;;3;1234567890;
```

I would like to try to get a target file (.txt) with the following structure:

```
Name1;Name2;Street;123;12345;1234567890;
```

In the target file, the structure would be such that I should write the first two values from the lines and the last value from the input file into a new line of the target file.

Can this be solved via batch?

Best regards,

BatPort2020

Comment: indirectly, I wrote this post with more detail

Comment: The [@Squashman's comment to the 1st version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879144/change-output-txt-file-by-batch#comment109447486_61879144) is still valid…

Comment: Also your example file structure has a remarkable similarity to those in [batch script adaption with following code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61561989), and [How do make a wait or sleep into a batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61568099).